# Optimizing setCellValueExplicit() in PHPExcel

Tags: php, performance, optimization, phpexcel

I am dealing with 700 rows of data in my excel.

And I add on a column this entry:

```
foreach($data as $k => $v){
   $users ->getCell('A'.$k)->setValue($v['Username']);
   $users->setCellValueExplicit('B'.$k, 
      '=INDEX(\'Feed\'!H2:H'.$lastRow.',MATCH(A'.$k.',\'Feed\'!G2:G'.$lastRow.',0))',
      PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_FORMULA);
}
```

`$users` stands for a spreadsheet.

I see that writing 700 cells with the above `setCellValueExplicit()` takes more than 2 minutes to get processed. If I omit that line it takes 4 seconds for the same machine to process it.

2 minutes can be ok, but what if I have 2000 cells. Is there any way that can be speed optimized?

ps: `=VLOOKUP` is the same slow as the above function.

---

**Update**

The whole idea of the script:
read a CSV file (13 columns and at least 100 rows), write it into a spreadsheet, create a new spreadsheet (`$users`), read two columns, sort them based to one column and write it to the `$users` spreadsheet.

Read the columns:

```
$data = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= $lastRow; $i++) {
    $user = $Feed ->getCell('G'.$i)->getValue();
    $number = $Feed ->getCell('H'.$i)->getValue();
    $row = array('User' => $user, 'Number' => $number);
    array_push($data, $row);
}
```

Sort the data

```
function cmpb($a,$b){
    //get which string is less or 0 if both are the same
    if($a['Number']>$b['Number']){
        $cmpb = -1;
    }elseif($a['Number']<$b['Number']){
        $cmpb = 1;
    }else{
        $cmpb = 0;
    }
    //if the strings are the same, check name
    if($cmpb == 0){
        //compare the name
        $cmpb = strcasecmp($a['User'], $b['User']);
    }
    return $cmpb;
}
usort($data, 'cmpb');
```

Write data

```
foreach($data as $k => $v){
   $users ->getCell('A'.$k)->setValue($v['Username']);
   $users ->getCell("B{$k}")->setValueExplicit("=INDEX('Feed'!H2:H{$lastRow},MATCH(A{$k},'Feed'!G2:G{$lastRow},0))",
 PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_FORMULA);
}
```

and also unset the data for memory:

```
unset($data);
```

So if comment the line with `setValueExplicit` everything becomes smoother.

Comment: The value you're setting on the `setCellValueExplicit` is a little unreadable due to all those concatenations and escape on the single quotes. You can replace it with `"=INDEX('Feed'!H2:H{$lastRow},MATCH(A{$k},'Feed'!G2:G{$lastRow},0))"`.

Comment: @RolandoIsidoro Unfortunately I cannot say that I saw improvement in performance.

Comment: That's why I added as a comment and not as an answer. I was just looking at PHPExcel's source code and I can't find a reason for the behaviour you describe. I'll add an answer with some considerations because it wouldn't fit the comments. Let me know what you think about it.

Comment: There's no logical reason why `setCellValueExplicit()` should be significantly slower than `getCell()->setValue()`, but you might try `getCell()->setValueExplicit()` as Rolando has suggested.

Comment: P.S. - I apologise for writing unreasonable code, feel free to look at alternatives. I won't force you to use PHPExcel

Comment: @MarkBaker PHPExcel is great so far and handy to use. It's a good puzzle for me to learn optimize my code. I just try to conceive why this is happening. I'll run the same script on a better server

Answer (score 3):

Looking at PHPExcel's source code, this is **PHPExcel_Worksheet::setCellValueExplicit** function:

```
public function setCellValueExplicitByColumnAndRow($pColumn = 0, $pRow = 1, $pValue = null, $pDataType = PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING)
{
    return $this->getCell(PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($pColumn) . $pRow)->setValueExplicit($pValue, $pDataType);
}
```

For the data type you're using, `PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_FORMULA`, the **PHPExcel_Cell::setValueExplicit** function just executes:

```
case PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_FORMULA:
    $this->_value = (string)$pValue;
    break;
```

I can't find a logical explanation for the old up on the execution of that particular instruction. Try to replace it for the following and let me know if there was any improvement:

```
$users ->getCell("B{$k}")->setValueExplicit("=INDEX('Feed'!H2:H{$lastRow},MATCH(A{$k},'Feed'!G2:G{$lastRow},0))", PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_FORMULA);
```

As a last resource my advice would be to time track the execution of the instruction to find the bottleneck.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it and it dropped the time from 2 minutes to one minute. I am still afraid that this is a lot though and quite unreasonable. I also run the script 2-3 times and I got `Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted`. 128 megabytes of memory... Any more ideas are welcome, thank you

Comment: If you can paste the `$data` set you're working with somewhere maybe I could try to speed it up.

Comment: If you're hitting memory problems as well, then you either need to increase your memory, or to use cell caching; but the latter will affect speed

Comment: Updated. `$data` is a 2x700 multidimensional array.